# SOAP requests using Savon

Tags: ruby, soap, savon, exacttarget

I dug as deep as I could but could not find a solution to my problem:

I want to send SOAP requests to ExactTarget API. I am trying to use Savon, but the requests it creates are different from those that worked with ExactTarget's API (I used Java previously) and in the end I get an error when running the Ruby script.

Below is the body of a working request that I am to create in Ruby:

```
<S:Body>
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>BounceEvent</ObjectType>
            <Properties>SendID</Properties>
            <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
            <Properties>EventDate</Properties>
            <Properties>SMTPCode</Properties>
            <Properties>BounceCategory</Properties>
            <Properties>SMTPReason</Properties>
            <Properties>BounceType</Properties>
            <Filter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                <Property>SendID</Property>
                <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                <Value>421939</Value>
            </Filter>
        </RetrieveRequest>
</RetrieveRequestMsg>
</S:Body>
```

Now here is the code I created in Ruby:

```
client = Savon.client do
  wsdl 'https://webservice.s4.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl'  
  wsse_auth("user", "pass")
end

builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
builder.instruct!(:xml, encoding: "UTF-8")

#builder.RetrieveRequestMsg('xmlns'=>'http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI') do
  builder.RetrieveRequest do
    builder.ObjectType "BounceEvent"
    builder.Properties "SendID"
    builder.Properties "SubscriberKey"
  end
#end

theBody = builder.target!
theBody.slice! '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'

client.call(:retrieve, message: theBody)
```

..and here is the resulting request body:

```
<env:Body>
    <tns:RetrieveRequestMsg>
        <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>BounceEvent</ObjectType>
            <Properties>SendID</Properties>
            <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
        </RetrieveRequest></tns:RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </env:Body>
```

...and here is the resulting error I get:

```
<soap:Body>
    <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <OverallStatus>Error</OverallStatus>
        <RequestID>5ce5cfae-85b4-4e76-b9dd-299e9a9ca871</RequestID>
    </RetrieveResponseMsg>
</soap:Body>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: My standard question: Have you tried it in SoapUI? Then build the Soap request with Savon. Savon uses a slightly different way to build a syntactically correct request than SoapUI or Java. Why do you use builder? Is a Savon message not enough?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `Builder`, try using `Savon`s `call` method for generating a SOAP request.

`ruby
response = client.call(:authenticate, message: { username: "luke", password: "secret" })`

You have the wsdl, so you should be able to determine the method name and arguments. Calling `.operations` on the client will list all of the available operations that you can generate.